# Finding sum of purchases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sum

Each `User` has many `Purchases`. I want to find the sum for each of the previous 28 days.

```
t1 = Time.now - (28.days)
t2 = Time.now
@dailysum = Array.new(29)
(0..29).each do |i|
  @dailysum[i] = @user.purchases.where(:created_at => (Time.now-(i.day))..(Time.now-((i-1).days))).sum(:amount)
end
```

This works, but I'm certain there is a much better way of going about this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a `:group` option to sum.  The value of the `:group` option is different based on your db.  I'll provide a pg and mysql version.

```
# purchases.rb
def self.recent(num)
  where('created_at > ?', num.days.ago
end

# PG version
@user.purchases.recent.sum(:amount, group: "DATE_PART('year', purchases.created_at) || '-' || DATE_PART('month', purchases.created_at) || '-' || DATE_PART('day', purchases.created_at)")

# mysql version
@user.purchases.recent.sum(:amount, group: "DATE(purchases.created_at)")
```

this will result in a hash where the keys is the date and the values are the sum of the purchases.

**This will result in 27 less queries compared to querying for each day for the last 28 days**

Answer (score 2):

### /!\ SEE MY OTHER (BETTER) ANSWER

This answer will calculate the **whole** sum of purchases of the last 28 days

Read my other answer for the calculation of the sum of **each** last 28 days.

I keep this one online for those who can be interested by it.

---

```
@user.purchases
    .where('created_at > ?', 28.days.ago) # retrieve all purchases within the last 28 days
    .sum(:amount)                         # get the sum of the amount column
```

If you want to use a scope, as proposed by @andy :

```
# in purchase.rb
scope :recent, ->(d) { where('created_at > ?', d.days.ago) }

# then in you controller
@user.purchases
  .recent(28)          # retrieve all purchases within the last 28 days
  .sum(:amount)        # get the sum of the amount column
```

Comment: You could also define a scope

Comment: A scope should be chainable, so why not, but without the `.pluck(:amount).sum` part. Only `scope :recent, -> { |d| where('created_at > ?', d.days.ago) }`

Comment: Oh I see! I've only just started using rails so thanks for that. My previous comment was a bit brief because I was trying to do two things at once haha

Comment: I can no longer edit my previous comment, but the scope definition is erroneous. It's corrected in my answer though.

Comment: you can replace pluck with sum so you don't generate an array.

Comment: What happens when you want an array for the last 28 days? Say some days had no purchases

Comment: I don't undestand. 28 days is 28 days. If i didn't make any purchase for last 28 days, so the sum is 0. If it's not what you want, then what you want? The last 28 purchases? So there is nothing to do with dates.

Comment: not every day has a purchase so for those days the sum should be 0. The returned array should have 28 values. So if there was no purchases in the last 28 days the returned array should have 28 0's.

Comment: Oh sh*t. I think i misunderstood the question. You want a distinct sum for every last 28 days? And not a sum of the last 28 days purchases?

Comment: yeah your code is putting my in the right direction though. Just trying to get the array with all the zero's should they be in there.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I've better understood the question, here is a second try.

It's hard to do this out of context.

```
user.purchases
  .where('created_at > ?', 28.days.ago)
  .group_by { |p| p.created_at.to_date }
  .collect { |d, ps| [d, ps.sum { |p| p.amount }]  }
```

That should return an array of arrays containing each the date and the amount sum for this date :

```
[
  ["Mon, 28 Jan 2013", 137],
  ["Tue, 29 Jan 2013", 49]
  ["Wed, 30 Jan 2013", 237]
]
```